# Android Studio(2.3.3), some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Tags: android

R.java is not getting created for any of the project.

Suddenly started facing this issue. Have tried almost everything suggested for this error.

- Tried shorting the project path.
- Tried changing Gradle version (Current is 3.3)
- Tried Invalidate Caches/ Restart.
- Tried building with no nine patch image.
- Tried Reinstalling Complete Android Studio and SDK.

Facing This issue for **all existing projects and even if I create a new project in a shorter path(C:\MyApplication)**.

Console Error Screen Shot for more details. [image]

I am trying to solve thus issue since 3 days, still no luck, can anybody help me on this, Please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: is your src file in the project dialog?

Comment: @Zoffa, i didn't get you.. can u please explain ?

Comment: try disabling the aapt cruncher by adding `aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
` to your build.gradle file

Comment: Have tried disabling the aapt as well !